# Make Inno Setup automatically add data from custom pages to .inf file

Tags: inno-setup

I created a installer with custom wizard pages. All works fine so far. 
Next I wanted to create a settings file using `/SAVEINF` (to start the installer later on in silent mode) using the following command:

```
Installer.exe /SAVEINF="Unattended.txt"
```

After entering all user input and running the installer, I looked at the file created. The only user input I see is the installation location but missing all my input on the custom wizard pages. All I see is:

```
[Setup]
Lang=en
Dir=C:\temp
Group=MyProgram
NoIcons=0
Tasks=
```

Why? What do I need to do to have the custom wizard page values also in the settings file?

---

To be more specific.
I start the installer I've created with option to create a settings file using the `/SAVEINF` option on the commandline. I expected all items to be added to this file including the one from my custom wizard pages, but that's not the case. I only see the installation location from the standard setup page.

Of course I can add them manually and implement in the installer code to read them from the file, but I expected it to be automated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inno Setup Load defaults for custom installation settings from a file (.inf) for silent installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624032/inno-setup-load-defaults-for-custom-installation-settings-from-a-file-inf-for)

Comment: Do I have to do it all by myself for all custom wizardpages I'vve created? I expected INNOSetup to create the file automatically when using the SAVEINFO option.

Comment: No it won't do it for you. I cannot even imagine this to be possible. How could it know, how to serialize your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, Inno Setup won't save any custom fields to the `.inf` file.

It will never save anything to the `.inf` file beyond the standard `Lang`, `Dir`, `Group`, `NoIcons`, `SetupType`, `Components` and `Tasks` items.

See [`SaveInf` function in Inno Setup source code](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_9/Projects/Main.pas#L657):

```pascal
procedure SaveInf(const FileName: String);
const
  Section = 'Setup';
begin
  SetIniString(Section, 'Lang',
    PSetupLanguageEntry(Entries[seLanguage][ActiveLanguage]).Name, FileName);
  SetIniString(Section, 'Dir', WizardDirValue, FileName);
  SetIniString(Section, 'Group', WizardGroupValue, FileName);
  SetIniBool(Section, 'NoIcons', WizardNoIcons, FileName);
  if WizardSetupType <> nil then begin
    SetIniString(Section, 'SetupType', WizardSetupType.Name, FileName);
    SetIniString(Section, 'Components', StringsToCommaString(WizardComponents), FileName);
  end
  else begin
    DeleteIniEntry(Section, 'SetupType', FileName);
    DeleteIniEntry(Section, 'Components', FileName);
  end;
  SetIniString(Section, 'Tasks', StringsToCommaString(WizardTasks), FileName);
end;
```

---

There are more items Inno Setup will *load* from the `.inf` file. See the [`LoadInf` function](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_9/Projects/Main.pas#L618). But again, not custom fields/pages. Just options that can otherwise be specified using command-line switches, like `Silent`, `VerySilent`, `NoRestart`, etc.

---

If you want custom fields in the `.inf` file, you have to implement them on your own:
[Inno Setup Load defaults for custom installation settings from a file (.inf) for silent installation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38624032/850848).

Comment: OK, clear. I will start implementing it myself based on the exmaple(s) given. Thanks.